# Change line width dynamically based on text width

Tags: qgis, print-composer, print-templates

How can you let the width of a vertical line change based on the width of the text in a label in the print composer? (Not looking for the underlined text style.)
An example of a line that underlines the text (from AutoCAD):
[image: What I want]

What I have now (a permanent long line under the text):
[image]

Comment: You should add more information and provide sample data (maybe also a screenshot) to make clear what you're asking about. Like it is written, it's difficult to understand the problem.

Comment: I've added pictures